# Android Splash Screen Animation (Left to Right)

Tags: android, android-animation, splash-screen

Currently, I am trying to create splash screen with this animation:
[Progress Bar Effect](https://gyazo.com/aad2fa7249632ab28502f4a1aa607fc2)

From the start, I thought of creating the progress bar, however, I can't make it and unable to find exact design. Thus, I was planning using animation method  but most of the tutorial are fade in/our or move the item from left to right.  Any idea how to create this kind of animation in splash screen (3 second)?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this manually using handler to make the images appear after period of time.

At first you will create a layout containing these images and make them invisible, then in the handler show them one by one.

here's how to do it.

this is in layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/presence_online"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/presence_online"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/presence_online"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/presence_online"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this in java class:

```
final int TIME_OUT = 1000;

        final ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
        final ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);
        final ImageView imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img3);
        final ImageView imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img4);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, TIME_OUT);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, TIME_OUT * 2);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, TIME_OUT * 3);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageView4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, TIME_OUT * 4);
```

you can change the TIME_OUT as it suits you and so the android:src.

i tried this and works well.

if there's anything not clear let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For the ProgressBar effect as indicator of progress, please look at the reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html). Also take a look at thread of suggestions as well as the selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766755/smooth-progress-bar-animation) - they show how to do a progress bar animation. You can also look at the selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097795/android-make-a-progress-bar-update-smoothly) about making the progress bar to update smoothly. I hope this points you in the right direction.