# How to set smoothly animation to progressBar in android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-progressbar

In my project I want use `ProgressBar` and I want set **smoothly countdown animation**.

I write below codes for **smoothly animation** and when set **1000ms (1s)** for **duration** show **smoothly** `animation`, but I want set **10000ms (10s)** for **duration**.

**When set 10000ms (10s) for duration not smoothly animation and show Fragmentary countdown.**

But I want set **10000ms** for **duration** and show **smoothly countdown**.

```
public class SimpleFrag extends Fragment {

    TextView toolbar_title;
    RelativeLayout toolbar;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_simple, container, false);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        toolbar_title = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        toolbar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @SuppressLint("ObjectAnimatorBinding")
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ProgressBarAnimation mProgressAnimation = new ProgressBarAnimation(progressBar, 79, 0);
                    mProgressAnimation.setDuration(10000);
                    progressBar.startAnimation(mProgressAnimation);
                }
            }, 50);
        }
    }

    public class ProgressBarAnimation extends Animation {
        private ProgressBar progressBar;
        private float from;
        private float to;

        public ProgressBarAnimation(ProgressBar progressBar, float from, float to) {
            super();
            this.progressBar = progressBar;
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
            float value = from + (to - from) * interpolatedTime;
            progressBar.setProgress((int) value);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I it? please help me . Thanks all <3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take what you have now, and delete your `setUserVisibleHint()` method and your `ProgressBarAnimation` class. Add this:

```
private void setUpObserver() {
    progressBar.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            startAnimation();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                progressBar.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
            else {
                progressBar.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void startAnimation() {
    int width = progressBar.getWidth();
    progressBar.setMax(width);

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, width);
    animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animator.setStartDelay(0);
    animator.setDuration(10_000);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            int value = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            progressBar.setProgress(value);
        }
    });

    animator.start();
}
```

Then, inside your `onCreateView()` method, call `setUpObserver()` right before you `return view;`

The `setUpObserver()` method uses an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to make sure that the system waits until the `ProgressBar` is measured an laid out before starting the animation.

The `startAnimation()` method is what takes care of actually setting up and running the animation. You can modify the values passed to `setStartDelay()` and `setDuration()` as you see fit.

The trick to this solution is making sure that the maximum value for the progress bar is equal to its width, meaning that each increment of "progress" is equal to one pixel on the screen. The android framework animation takes care of making sure everything runs as smoothly as possible.

### Edit

If you want to be able to control the start/end points for the animation (rather than just go from empty to full), make these changes:

Change the declaration of `startAnimation()` to this:

```
private void startAnimation(float startPercent, float endPercent)
```

Delete this line from inside `startAnimation()`

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, width);
```

and add these lines instead:

```
int start = (int) (startPercent * width);
int end = (int) (endPercent * width);
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);
```

Finally, call `startAnimation()` by passing in fractional percentages:

```
startAnimation(0.79f, 0.10f); // will animate from 79% to 10%
```

Comment: thanks but I want set from and to values for show progress. such as start from 79 and end in 0 . how can I it in your code? can you send to me code? I am amateur and I really need your help. please

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: and in your help, not countdown. I want start from 100, to 0 . but in your code start from 0 to 100 ! I want start from 100, to 0 . how can I it? please help me my friend. pleaseeee

Comment: thanks my friend, can you send to me your edit code inside one full code? such as your above full code. please my friend, please :(

Comment: really I am amateur and need your help. please

Comment: I edit your code and fix my issue. thaaaaaaaaaaaaanks my friend for you help. thanks